# prawn unicode characters rendering

Tags: utf-8, rendering, prawn

I am trying to use [prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/) to generate PDF with Unicode characters. I checked that Arial font from corefonts package contains required characters, registered it, and chosen as default font:

```rb
 font_path = "/usr/share/fonts/corefonts/"
 font_families.update("sans" => {
   normal: { file: "#{font_path}/arial.ttf" },
   bold:   { file: "#{font_path}/arialbd.ttf" },
   bold_italic:   { file: "#{font_path}/arialbi.ttf" }
 })

 font "sans"
```

Now I'm trying to output Unicode text in `formatted_text_box` like this:

```rb
  formatted_text_box [{text: my_text, font: "sans", size: 14, styles: [:bold]}], 
      at: [10, 160], 
      align: :center, 
      width: 330,
      height: 20,
      overflow: :shrink_to_fit
```

Unfortunately, text is not bold and there are no non-ascii characters displayed. If I change styles parameter to `[:normal]` it's OK, but I need it bold.

Moreover, if before the call to `formatted_text_box` I put this:

```rb
  text "anything"
```

The text in `formatted_text_box` is rendered correctly!

It happens for both: 0.12.0 and 1.0.0.rc2.

Am I doing something wrong?